# Modifying my dmp (data management platform) profile

Tags: ads, dmp

I would like to modify (programmatically or manually) my dmp profile. *The motivation is to investigate the correlation between my profile (interests/GEO/sex/age etc) and the ads I receive.*

Modifying the Google profile is quite easy via:
https://www.google.com/settings/u/0/ads/authenticated

I would like to be able to modify my **Lotame**'s, **Bluekai**'s etc profiles.

For Bluekai and Lotame I found there preference managers:

http://www.bluekai.com/registry

https://www.lotame.com/opt-out-preference-manager/

The **Bluekai**'s one allows me to remove some of the data it collected (in location, interests etc sections).

The **Lotame**'s one looks not working and the following message is displayed: "*Please wait while we load your profile*"

I have to be able not only to remove some profile data (interests/GEO/sex/age etc), but also to add/modify it.

I was thinking of finding out which activity on which sites I should perform to effect my profile. Still I don't know which sites and which activity.

May be there are some other ways I didn't think about?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

DMP's interest management works quite different from Google Audiences. Each company decides how you will be tracked and if those behaviors belongs to declared or behavioral data.

The URLs that you shared should works for this purpose. If you have any problem, you should be able to manage your opt-outs here: http://optout.networkadvertising.org/?c=1

Anyway, there is no DMP company that has a service in which the user declares specific interest for their profiling.

Hope this helps :-)